what's the purpose of lookup tables since you need to send several transactions to create the LUT?
i first thought the lookup tables could be used to fit more instructions in a single transaction, because of the indexing accounts feature. The goal on my side would be to reduce the number of signatures.
But i read that to create the lookup table, you can only add +/- 20 accounts per transaction in the LUT. So it won't really reduce the number of signatures needed.
Is there something  i got wrong ?

A few things to clarify about lookup tables:
When you add an account to a lookup table, it's there for future transactions. So the idea is to build it up and then use it later as many times as you want. This is particularly useful when you need a lot of accounts in one transaction. For example, Jupiter uses lookup tables extensively to facilitate swaps across multiple protocols in one transaction.
In your transaction, you can use as many of those accounts as you want, with a maximum of 64 accounts total.
Accounts that sign the transaction cannot be in lookup tables, however. Otherwise, the runtime would need to load lookup table accounts in order to verify signatures, which would slow down signature verification and require a connection to the accounts database.
